# How to get port, connection details

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, data-visualization, draw2d

I am using draw2d with React. I have the node, ports, and connections working.
My Questions are

1. How to get the connected ports, am using canvas.
2. How to get the connection path details between ports.
3. Capture click events on the ports.
4. Capture click events on the connections. using new draw2d.Connection({})

versions

```
 "dependencies": {
   "draw2d": "1.0.19",
   "jquery": "3.4.1",
   "jquery-ui-bundle": "1.12.1-migrate",
   "react": "16.8.6",
   "react-dom": "16.8.6",
   "react-scripts": "2.1.8"
 },
```

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions.

Comment: FYI I contributed by editing your post. You might have better chances of getting proper answers if you focus on a single question in your post.